# How to get the amount of unique labels in a Loki/Grafana Query

Tags: logging, devops, grafana, grafana-loki, logql

for some context we migrated from Elastic/Kibana to Loki/Grafana and imported several years of logs, all is going well, I can query the logs and explore as expected. Now I'm in the process of building the dashboards we had in Kibana and I'm having problems getting the results I need.

The panel I'm having problems with just has a number of active users in a time period, in which case `active_user_id` is a label and I just need to get the count of unique `active_user_id` values.

I have this LogQL query, which if I run it gives me 97 independent values with the count of times each label value is present in the time interval, but I just need to get `97` in the dashboard, however I can't accomplish that.

`count by (active_user_id) (count_over_time({type="request"}[$__interval]))`

I also tried this query, which returns 272, this being the amount of different timestamps where there are logs:

`count(count by (active_user_id) (count_over_time({type="request"}[$__interval])))`

I think I'm pretty close but not sure what I'm missing as this is my first time using loki and grafana.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You second query should not return 272 based on you description, but in fact should return 97 exactly like you expect it to. Please recheck query being used and it's output.

Answer (score 2):

Your first query is good since it gives you a table of the active users against the number of occurrences. You need to use the `$__range` in place of `$__interval` so that the count is done over the whole time range instead of each interval. So instead of

```
count by (active_user_id) (count_over_time({type="request"}[$__interval]))
```

use

```
count(count(count_over_time({type="request"}[$__range])) by (active_user_id))
```

which will give you the number of active_user_id in the whole time range you are interested in. I believe that should give you the `97` you desire in your panel.

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the parenthesis @markalex.

Comment: I used the $__range keyword instead to count over the full range that is specified instead of in the interval. Shouldn't that solve the issue?